# Is it possible to rewrite complex EF Core ".Include" calls to "Join" calls?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two EF Core entity models named Service and ServiceBranch:

```
public class Service
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentServiceID { get; set; } // foreign key to the same table
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> InverseParent { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceBranch> ServiceBranches { get; set; } // navigation property
}

public class ServiceBranch
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ServiceID { get; set; } // foreign key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

For simplicity, let's say parent Service can have only one level of children Services. both parent and children services are being referenced by a lot of service branches.

I want to update DateDeleted field for a specific Service ID and update DateDeleted in all other rows that are referencing it (if that field doesn't already have a value).

Currently my call to bring all the required entities looks like this:

```
var serviceEntity = _context.Set<Service>().Where(x => x.ID == neededID && x.DateDeleted == null)
                .Include(x => x.ServiceBranches)
                .Include(x => x.InverseParent)
                    .ThenInclude(InverseParent => InverseParent.ServiceBranches)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I use Where clause for the main entity but unfortunately I cannot use Where inside .Includes since we haven't upgraded to EF Core 5.0 yet (which supports filtering inside .Includes).

Thus I bring too many unneeded rows (where DateDeleted already has a value) from the database and then filter them within a foreach loop by comparing that field to null:

```
if (myentity.DateDeleted == null) myentity.DateDeleted = DateTime.Now;
```

I want to rewrite my query so that I use "join" instead of ".Include", something like this:

```
var serviceEntity = from service in _context.Set<Service>()
                where service.ID == neededID && service.DateDeleted == null
                join branches in _context.Set<ServiceBranch>() on service.ID equals branches.ServiceID
                where branches.DateDeleted == null // filter which I cannot use with .Include-s
                let // whatever, can't make it work
                select // etc
```

I can't get my head around how to rewrite it. Or if it is even possible to do it with joins.

Comment: There are countless questions about filtered include while it wasn't supported yet. You should be able to find work-arounds in many of them. One tip: don't join. Use the same navigation properties as Include does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case you don't need joins, but flat list containing the desired `Service` entity plus all its children. In general this requires recursive query (not supported by LINQ / EF Core), but for single level it is a matter of simple filter like

```
service.ID == neededID || service.ParentServiceID == neededID
```

Then you could apply the additional `DateDeleted` criteria. Finally, to get the related `ServiceBranch` entities with `DateDeleted` filter, instead of `Include` just use projection (`Select`).

And when processing the returned data, use the projected entities and ignore their navigation properties. e.g.

```
var itemsToUpdate = _context.Set<Service>()
    .Where(service => (service.ID == neededID || service.ParentServiceID == neededID)
        && service.DateDeleted == null)
    .Select(service => new
    {
        Service = service,
        ServiceBrances = service.ServiceBranches
            .Where(branch => branch.DateDeleted == null),
    });

foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
{
    item.Service.DateDeleted = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var branch in item.ServiceBrances)
        branch.DateDeleted =  DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Include` puts the loaded objects directly on your Entity Framework model, and that model is really supposed to directly represent what's in the database. If you're wanting a filtered collection, I'd recommend coming up with a different model that represents what you're trying to represent, and then using Select to project to that model. Something like this:

```
var serviceEntity = _context.Set<Service>()
    .Where(x => x.ID == neededID && x.DateDeleted == null)
    .Select(x => new // you can make this a named type if necessary
        {
           Service = x,
           ActiveBranches = x.ServiceBranches.Where(b => b.DateDeleted == null),
           InverseParent,
           InverseParentServiceBranches = x.InverseParent.ServiceBranches
        })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So going for joins was wrong direction after all. Thanks